# Express.js and Angular.js html5mode (Avoiding # in url)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, html5mode

I have been working on avoiding # in Angular app with ExpressJS serverside.
I have researched how to enable html5mode and it worked great. But whenever there is another 'get' request to retrieve data from another url such as /api/services, it seems like somehow broken and do not provide data properly to the page.

Here's what I have done in express end.

```
router.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
router.get('/api/service-edit', function (req, res, next) {
  Service.find(function (err, services) {
    if (err) {return next(err);}
    res.json(services);
  });
});
```

I am not 100% sure, but what I guess is '/*' causes a problem for the server in reading api urls.
I am wondering if any of you have an experience in this problem and a solution to figure this out.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In expressjs the routing rules are matched in the order you present them in the code. So the '/*' rule is always matched first and the second rule is never reached.

Putting the second rule before the first one will probably solve the problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed order of the routing syntax in the main app.js as you pointed. I was struggling with this problem for two days and finally got this. I really appreciate you for saving my time!